# DC motor won't spin without a push

Tags: dc-motor

just got this http://www.robotshop.com/en/rs-775-motor-7000rpm-12v-7613oz-in.html

I hook it up to 12VDC power source for a test ; the motor doesn't run without a push and I read 4V, 0.46A on my source. As soon as I remove contact with DC motor, I read 12V on my source.

Does someone have an idea what could be wrong ?

Comment: No Load current is 0.80A from datasheet

Answer (score 4):

You're using far too small a power supply. Apparently it can only provide about 0.5 amps to a motor that needs (nominally) 0.8 amps to run at no load. Worse, at startup the motor will pull stall current (see the specs), for an instantaneous current of 34 amps.

So basically you need a bigger power supply. A 12 volt, 5 to 10 amp unit sounds about right.

Comment: I have 34V, 5A Max as source

Comment: @DavidPatry - OK, so why was your current limiting at .46 amps? Didn't it occur to you to change the current limit?

Comment: If you don't have a current limit set, it sounds like your "5A" supply has foldback protection, so that when it trips, both the output voltage and current reduce. Really you need a better power supply but you might have some luck with a soft starter - like a series resistor to limit the stall current to 5A at 12V. Given the winding resistance of 12/34 ohms (datasheet) about 2 or 2.2 oms should do it. When the motor's running, short out the resistor.

Answer (score 0):

Increase the current limit from 0.46 A to something higher on your power supply. You appear to be in CC-mode.